# Wrong checkout URL after migration

Tags: checkout, url-rewrite

I'm using Magento 1.9.1. I tried to migrate from http://www.example.com to http://www.example2.com/subfolder/shop/, and I changed the records `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in table `core_config_data` to `http://www.example2.com/subfolder/shop/`. I then refreshed the indexes and caches in Magento CMS.

However, when I try to add products to cart, it requested this URL: `http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/` instead of `http://www.example2.com/subfolder/shop/checkout/cart/add/`.

Which config did I miss?

---

**UPDATE** I found out that the form action URL of the product list page is set to `/checkout/cart/add/` instead of `checkout/cart/add/`, which makes the form submission URL is incorrect. How do I resolve?

Comment: Do quick Search in Core_config_data table with your old directory path , see if the old one is still there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the old path does not exist in `core_config_data` anymore...

Comment: Did you searched using " select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%' " or manually ? have you deleted var cache / sessions folder ?

Comment: both `/var/cache/` and `/var/sessions/` are empty.